# Leaflet API Overlaying Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I currently have an issue in which the Leaflets mapping API is currently showing in front of my dropdown menu overlaying it and hiding it, however, does not currently stop the user from using the drop downs nor the map.

Current Page `HTML`
and
Current `CSS` (only for the map space, drop downs and the columns below the map)

```css
body #mapspce{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#444444;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding 10px;
  text-align: center;   
}
/*dropdown menu*/

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .but {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .but:hover{
  color:#0080ff;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:#737373;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.titlelink a {
  color:#0080ff;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font:18px;
}

.btmtxtsect{
  text-align: center;
  /*border: 3px solid green;*/
}

/*columns and rows for GIS explinations*/

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
}
.row:after {
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}



/*Footer*/
footer{
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#119108;
  border-top:#000 3px solid;
  text-align:center;
}

footer.gis{
  background-color:#444444;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="eng">

<!--Meta data and title of the page-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="Author" content="Tom Slater 18018815 USW">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../tut.css">
  <title>GIS Tutorials</title>
  <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
</head>

<body>


<!--nav bar-->

<header>
<!--contains the information within the header allowing for borders and text manipulation-->
<div class = "container">
<!--Displays the title whilst highlighting it-->
<div id = "title">
<h1><span class = "highlightlink">GIS TUTORIALS</span></h1>
</div>

<!--Nav Bar-->
<div class="dropdown">
<!--Assignment One GIS CW pt 1 (google maps & Bing)-->
<button class="but">Assignment 1<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<!-- LINK for Marker Page-->
<a href="../mapicon.htm">Markers Task</a>
<!--LINK for Lines Tutorials-->
<a href="../maplines.html">Polylines Task</a>
<!--LINK for Polygons Task-->
<a href="../polygons.html">Polygons Task</a>
<!--LINK for info windows-->
<a href="../infowind.html">Info Windows Task</a>
<!--LINK for KLM Maps Features-->
<a href="../klm.html">KLM Features</a>
<!--LINK for Bing-->
<a href="../bing.html">Bing</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
<!--Assignment Two GIS CW pt 2 (leaflet & Open Layers)-->
<button class="but">Assignment 2</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<!--Link for Leaflet-->
<a href="">Leaflet</a>
<!--Link for Open Layers-->
<a href="openlayer.htm">Open Layers</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<!--Assignment Three GIS CW pt 3 (Server side poo)-->
<button class="but">Assignment 3</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<!--Link for...-->
<a href="">Serverside 1</a>
<!--Link for ...-->
<a href="">Serverside 2</a>
</div>
</div>




</div>
</header>
<!--map space-->
<div id="mapspce">

<!--MAP SCRIPT-->
<script>
<!--Instantiating the map-->
  var Leafmap = L.map('mapspce', {
  center: [51.5, -3.4],
  zoom: 9
  });

<!--Adding the tile-->
L.tileLayer('https://tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=2392bb5236f942d8897fbe6d6c2d0c66',{
  maxZoom: 19,
  transparent: true,
  attribution: 'Tom Slater 18018815 &copy;, <a href="https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/transport/">Thunderforest</a> &copy;'
  }).addTo(Leafmap);

</script>

</div>


<!--Testx section explaining the map-->
<div class="btmtxtsect">
<div class="row">

<div class="column" style="Background-color:#bbb">
<h3>About this map</h3>
<p>The theme of this map is transport. The map shows rail lines and their stations, tramlines and roads from all over the world.
<br>
<br>
The map features data about ... from ...
</p>
</div>

<div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc">
<h3>Features Of this map</h3>
<ul>
<li>Markers</li>
<li>Polylines</li>
<li>GEO SPATIAL DATA</li>
<li>ETC</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>

</div>




</body>
<footer class ="gis">
Tom Slater 18018815 &copy;
</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:
Z indexing-

The map itself was overlaying and must have had a hidden Z index within the API, this was overlaying most things above it.

In changing the .Dropdown-content class to a higher Z index of 20 the drop down menu was able to display over the map once again.

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

However, this led to the issue that the map and its various buttons could not be clicked. In a fix to this the .mapspce class was also give a defined Z-index of a lower value than that of the drop down of 1 and the parent .dropdown class a z-index of 999 to ensure it will still be in front of the map.

```
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
    z-index:999;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 20;
}

body #mapspce{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#444444;
    border: 4px solid black;
    padding 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:1;  
}
```

Setting out a Z-index helps you to layer sections of HTML allowing certain areas to appear in front of others. This too is important when interacting with an API as this information is not necessarily given and playing around may be needed.